# Flexbox with flex:1 child and grandchild with 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Imagine having this situation: a simple 3 rows layout made with flexbox, with the central row filling all the space available. Pretty standard stuff.

```html
<body>
   <div class="container">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div>header</div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="item red">asdasd</div>
                <div class="item yellow">asdasd</div>
                <div class="item green">asdasd</div>
            </div>
            <div>footer</div>
        </div>
   <div>
<body>
```

Here the CSS:

```css
html,
body,
.container {
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container .content {
    flex: 1;
}

.flex-container .content .item {
    height: 100%;
}
```

(omitting css for background colors, you can guess it).

The problem is that the "content" div does not push down the footer div, keeping it at the bottom of the page, like is position:fixed with bottom: 0.
Scrolling the page show, except for this problem, the correct behavior, with 3 div with different color all sizing 100% the browser window.

What I'm missing?

**EDIT**: look at this jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rq1xywng/

Comment: `height: 100%` on `body` will do nothing unless you also specify a height for `html`. You are also missing a semicolon after the first two `height: 100%`

Comment: `body {height: 100vh}`

Comment: fixed code as @Turnip suggested, the problem remains. I've tried realtime

Comment: You are talking about a fixed-position footer, but you didn't post any CSS for that? And it's still unclear what you want to achieve...

Comment: What I'm saying is the footer is behaving like is "position:fixed; bottom: 0". What I'm trying to do is to push it to bottom, after the "content" div ends scrolling

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/tpsLmfca/

Comment: @Turnip almost. The header should scroll away, and I can't see the footer in your jsfiddlle

Comment: _" I can't see the footer in your jsfiddlle"_ make sure the console is not displaying (turn it off in settings). _"The header should scroll away"_ It sounds like flex is not the correct approach. You just want a fixed position footer.

Comment: Damn, I didn't know about the console. Thanks!!!
I dont want anything fixed, just the regular flow. But every child of "content" to be 100% in height. If .item has a px value, like 500, it is working. I'll find another way as you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have couple of errors here:

- you set EVERY ITEM IN THE CONTAINER to be 100% - this amounts to 300% :)
- their parent is "only" 100%
- footer will be hidden unless given height
- you used vh and % combined in an unhealthy way.

you should have 2 flex components:

- `.flex-container` - to match to screen size
- `.flex-container .content` - to be able to stretch the items

You should set `.item` to `flex: 1;`

Here is a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/oj0thmv7/5/

Here is a working example with scroll: https://jsfiddle.net/oyLbxsrc/

Comment: I ended up using javascript to calculate height to achieve what I wanted visually. But thanks to you @Itamar you gave me interesting ideas for another project.

Comment: Would be happy if you could add your solution to the post, for future searches

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about what you are looking for. May be it will be help for you.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
.header, .footer {
  height: 30px;
}

.flex-container .content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}

.flex-container .content .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="item red">asdasd</div>
      <div class="item yellow">asdasd</div>
      <div class="item green">asdasd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you change the 100% to 100vh this works

```
.flex-container .content .item {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Or have I misunderstood the issue?

Comment: Thanks @Itamar can you please let me know why this is not correct CSS wise? This is not argumentative, it is to help me understand better.

Comment: you set all items to take 100% of View Height

Comment: instead of stretching the items on the existing screen, like asked

Comment: Basically, you found the perfect band-aide solution instead of fixing the broken bicycle :)

Comment: Thanks Itamar makes perfect sense :)

Comment: Happy to help. Hope my own answer will be the correct one for the OP